# svn co answered "svn: Caught signal"

Tags: svn

I started svn co "path for the project from svn repository" and I've got such answer:

```
A    GI/prototypes
A    GI/prototypes/readme.txt
A    Environment
A    Environment/none_checkable_files.txt
A    Environment/ant.cmd
svn: Caught signal
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Did you get frustrated and hit "Control-C", because "Control-C" throws a signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means someone killed the process. That means an administrator on your computer killed it manually or the system is configured to stop runaway processes which eat too many resources (CPU, RAM, simultaneously open files).

Just try `svn so` again, Subversion should continue.